# Getting all members list (from a group I own) using Facebook Graph API - doesn't get the whole list - What part is wrong in my code?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I started working with the Facebook Graph API and noticed that when trying to get all the member list from my group (that I own), echo-ed the user name and I get only (around) 4900 users as an output - I have 15K+ users in my group!!!
To test that I var_dump-ed every list and it gave me 127 arrays with the text *"more elements..."* so I concluded that echoing the list was good, but getting the lists was wrong.

[image]

I tried to get the members list using the Graph API Explorer and it gave the same results with wrong "next" links with strange offset and limit parameters that don't make any sense and that I didn't enter.

This is my code for now (scroll to "Cool Stuff Here"):

```
 <?php

    session_start();

  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

  use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

  $app_id = '13434480350553256103140350';
  $app_secret = 'a866dcd372123fc87373a345cvvf34d0e70c3cdf0vvc13db4521basdd99';
  $redirect_url = 'http://localhost/test/YellowSpider/src/';

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $app_id, $app_secret );

  //helper for redirect
  $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url); 

  // Requested permissions for the app - optional
  $permissions = array(
    'email',
    'user_location',
    'user_birthday', 
    'user_groups'
  );


  // Check if existing session exists
  if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // Create new session from saved access_token
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

      // Validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
      try {
        if ( ! $session->validate() ) {
          $session = null;
        }
      } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        // Catch any exceptions
        $session = null;
      }
  } else {
    // No session exists
    try {
      $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect(); ////Processes the redirect data from Facebook, if present. Returns a FacebookSession or null.
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {

      // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {

      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo $ex->message;
    }
  }




  // Check if a session exists
  if ( isset( $session ) ) {

    // Save the session
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();

    // Create session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
    $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );


      /********************************* Cool Stuff Here *****************************************/


      $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/1501313558474010996619/members'); //Represents a request that will be made against the Graph API.

      //From the response - get graph object
      $response = $request->execute(); //Returns a Facebook\FacebookResponse from this request, from which a strongly-typed result can be retrieved. 
                                       //Throws an exception if the request fails. If the error is returned from Facebook, 
                                       //as opposed to a networking issue, a Facebook\FacebookRequestException is thrown.




      $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
      var_dump($graphObject);
      while($response){  

        var_dump($graphObject['data']);


        //echo $members['id'];



        if($response->getRequestForNextPage() != null){

          $response = $response->getRequestForNextPage()->execute();
          var_dump($response->getRequestForNextPage());
          continue;
        }else{
          break;
        }
      }








      /********************************* END Cool Stuff Here *****************************************/



    // Create the logout URL (logout page should destroy the session)
    $logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://localhost/test/YellowSpider/src/' );

    session_destroy(); // added this, clears all sessions. 
    echo '<a href="' . $logoutURL . '">Log out</a>';

  } else {
    // No session

    // Get login URL
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( $permissions );

    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in</a>';
  }
```

What can be my problem? Is my code written ok? Might it be a temporary problem with Facebook?

With my experience with PHP, using GET and POST, GET is kinda limited when passing parameters while POST is not, But with the FB API I guess there isn't any connection to this because the POST method there is used for literally, post things on Facebook (?)

Comment: NOTICE EVERYONE - this is a known bug of Facebook. in order to "help" facebook decide to fix it, you should all subscribe to this bug and comment that you need it fixed. here is the bug: developers.facebook.com/bugs/267362886791339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known Facebook bug (for more than 2 years) in a low priority fix.

To bypass this I think scrapping is the only best option, nevertheless, https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: For the record, here is the bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/267362886791339/

Comment: Almost a year later since the last comment and this bug is still present. I'm just starting to develop with this SDK and it's a little disheartening to know something like this exists.

Comment: NOTICE EVERYONE - in order to "help" facebook decide to fix it, you should all subscribe to this bug and comment that you need it fixed. here is the bug: developers.facebook.com/bugs/267362886791339